# Java: See if Mouse is hovering/clicking Sprite

Tags: java, game-design, mouse

The game I am developing is in which you defend the Cell from the Viruses, and I need the sprites to have a `MouseListener` for when the mouse clicks on that `sprite`, it will get destroyed, and I cannot figure out how to get the location of the mouse and apply it to the sprite.

Basically, I need to grab the location of the `mouse` and the `sprite`, and when the user clicks it will reset the `sprite`.

I have tried to do debugging with this, so like if the mouse hovers the location of the sprite it will print a message "Hovering" but it just doesn't work.

For my update method, I added:

```
if(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation() == this.getLocation()) System.out.println("SAME LOCATION");
```

I even got it to print out the location of the sprite and the mouse, and I aligned them both to `0`,`0` and it still didn't work.

CONCLUSION:
How do I check if the location of the mouse is the same as a sprite, and then print out a message to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your approach and problem correctly, you should use the following algorithm:

```
Obtain the minimum and maximum coordinates of the sprite.
Obtain the position of the mouse pointer.
Test both axes within a range.
```

The first requires the dimensions of the sprite and it's position.  Let's say its position is relative to the top-left of the sprite.  Pseudo-code would look like this (my Java is rusty):

```
int minx = this.getPosition().x();
int miny = this.getPosition().y();
int maxx = minx + this.getWidth();
int maxy = miny + this.getHeight();

int mousex = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x();
int mousey = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y();

if ((mousex >= minx && mousex <= maxx) && (mousey >= miny && mousey <= maxy) {
    System.out.println("Clicked on the sprite.");
    // Some reset code.
}
```

Comment: Yes this does work, thank you for that! The only error that occurs is that the mouse gets the `screen` locations, and not the `JFrame` locations. How would I add into the method to get the literal location on the screen?